# Hide/Show using CSS does not display content in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I'm struggling to find an answer.

I'm having trouble making this show/hide code work in Chrome. The content does not show when clicked. It works perfectly in IE and Firefox.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kogan/SJ8w7/)

```
 .hide {display: none;
 }
 #list {display: none;
 }
  .show:focus { display: none;
 }
  .show:focus + .hide {display: inline;
 }
  .show:focus ~#list{ display:block;
 }






<a href="#" class="show" tabindex="2">show</a>
            <a href="#" class="hide" tabindex="1">hide</a>      
<div id="list">
      Content here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, should work fine.

```
       <span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
        <span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
         <p class="content" >My content here</p>
```

css

```
 body {
   display: block;
  }
  .span3:focus ~ .content {
    display: none;
    }
  .span2:focus ~ .content{
     display: block;
   }
```